# Optimal Struct size for modern systems

Tags: c++, c

I've read that the ideal size of a structure for performance, that's going to be used in a large collection, is 32 bytes. Is this true and why? Does this effect 64bit processors or is it not applicable?

This is in context of modern (2008+) home Intel-based systems.

Comment: Presumably on the basis of maximally efficient read/write alignment size or something to do with the cache. Meh! This too will pass.

Comment: For some applications alignment probably counts for a lot more than size.

Comment: From the limit of 32bit I can assume that the reason for this is to be able to put the entire structure in a register for faster access and use.

Comment: Without resorting to compiler extensions, you don't really have a choice anyway, as structs will be padded to meet the alignment requirements of its members.

Comment: Define 'Optimal'. Do you mean optimal in terms of passing the object around (packed so it fits into a register). Do you mean optimal in terms of accessing the elements (packed objects are expensive to access). Do you mean optimal in terms of transporting across the wire. Do you mean optimal in terms of time required to compressing/decompressing for transport. Do you mean optimal in terms of making the source code readable. etc.etc.etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal size of a structure is likely to be one cache line (or a sub-multiple thereof).  Level one cache lines are typically 32 or 64 **bytes**. Splitting an element of a data structure across a cache line boundary will require two main memory accesses to read or write it instead of one.

Comment: What if the compiler optimizes the structure so it fits in a register is their a relationship between cache line size and register size?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. If your struct only needs to contain 1 bit of data, wasting a whole 32 or 64 bytes on each one is just going to waste A LOT more cache lines. The only time it might make sense to have such wasteful padding is when the number of objects is very small and they're being accessed from different threads running on different cores.

Comment: @Loki: Compiler really does not have the freedom to play with structure sizes like this. Even if it didn't have a fixed ABI to work with, the C standard places requirements on the relative arrangement of structures whose initial subsequence of elements agree that make it impossible to simultaneously "optimize" the size of multiple structures with padding.

Comment: Perfect size = register size (where optimal mean passing by value). If the struct is already < sizeof(register) then perfect. Otherwise not. But you are correct that if it is already bigger than a register there is little you can do to make it smaller so your structure better by a single int or double or very short string.

Comment: The OP was asking about structures, which are typically larger than a single word (or register).  No one in their right mind would suggest padding a single bit to 64 bytes! My point was that if you have a an array of structures that have for example a size of 60 bytes you will get better performance if you pad the structure to a size of 64 bytes.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't want a struct of 1 byte padded by 32 bytes. I was looking at a situation like you have said above where the structure is very close to the 32 or 64 byte size where the padding can help performance.

Comment: the only correct answer. and as often seen on SO is least popular.. also worth to note: my desktop now have 32 KiB L1 size. times are changing

Answer (score 10):

The ideal size of a struct is enough to hold the information it needs to contain.

Comment: +1 anyway but I think my answer was a little more detailed version of this. :-)

Comment: @R..: I actually was going to elaborate on that a bit, but I had to leave.  Now I think I'll just leave it alone.

Answer (score 6):

The optimal size for a struct is usually the minimum size needed to store whatever data it's supposed to contain without requiring any hacks like bit twiddling/misaligned accesses to make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reasonable answer to your question. Without any information on the context of the application, the "ideal size of a structure" is way, way underspecified.

As an aside, 32 bits is the space of one modern integer -- it isn't large enough for a "struct" except of a couple of characters or bitfields.

Comment: The question says "32 **bytes**" not bits. Markgz correctly points out that this fits nice in single cache lines.